# Push destructured values from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6

I'm slightly stuck with the `ES6 array.prototype` methods and don't really know how to implement this properly. The goal is to map the following object (let's assume it's called `attribues`) and get `attribute_label` value into a new array. It is also important to check this value to avoid null. The result should be a new array, full of string values:

```json
{
    "size": {
        "attribute_label": "Size",
        "code": null
    },
    "color": {
        "attribute_label": "Color",
        "code": 24
    },
    "material": {
        "attribute_label": "Material",
        "code": null
    }
}
```

Comment: What methods have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: 'It is also important to check this value to avoid null' ... you mean check attribute_label is not null or the code property is not null as your example seems to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to grab the values from the object:

```js
const attributes = {
  size: {
    attribute_label: "Size",
    code: null,
  },
  color: {
    attribute_label: "Color",
    code: 24,
  },
  material: {
    attribute_label: "Material",
    code: null,
  },
};

const labels = Object.values(attributes)
  .filter((val) => val !== null) // filter out null values
  .map(({ attribute_label }) => attribute_label);

console.log(labels);
// ["Size", "Color", "Material"]
```

If the `attribute_value` itself can be `null` (instead of the value in the object), just add another `.filter()` at the end.

```js
const attributes = {
  size: {
    attribute_label: "Size",
    code: null,
  },
  color: {
    attribute_label: "Color",
    code: 24,
  },
  material: {
    attribute_label: "Material",
    code: null,
  },
  another: null,
  another_attribute: {
    attribute_label: null,
    code: null,
  },
};

const labels = Object.values(attributes)
  .filter((val) => val !== null) // filter out null values
  .map(({ attribute_label }) => attribute_label)
  .filter((label) => label !== null); // filter out null labels inside the object

console.log(labels);
// ["Size", "Color", "Material"]
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use `Object.values` to create an `Array` with the content of the `Object`, then map those values to extract only the `attribute_label` property and finally filter the `Array` to skip `null` values:

```js
const data = {
  "size": {
    "attribute_label": "Size",
    "code": null
  },
  "color": {
    "attribute_label": "Color",
    "code": 24
  },
  "material": {
    "attribute_label": "Material",
    "code": null
  }
};

const values = Object.values(data);
const attributeLabels = values.map(value => value.attribute_label);
const withoutNulls = attributeLabels.filter(label => label !== null);

console.log(withoutNulls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.values and a forEach to push in a label array

```
const attributes_labels = []
Object.values(attributes).forEach(attribute => {
   if (attribute.attribute_label) {
     attributes_labels.push(attribute.attribute_label);
   }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm beating a dead horse here, but here is my solution, which is very similar to everyone else's:

```js
const data = {
  size: {
    attribute_label: 'Size',
    code: null,
  },
  color: {
    attribute_label: 'Color',
    code: 24,
  },
  material: {
    attribute_label: 'Material',
    code: null,
  },
};

const result = Object.values(data)
  .map(value => value.attribute_label)
  .filter(label => label !== null);
```